# Using Triggers To Enforce Constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers, constraints

I'm trying to enforce integrity on a table in a way which I do not think a Constraint can...

```
CREATE TABLE myData
(
   id             INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   fk_item_id     INTEGER               NOT NULL,
   valid_from     DATETIME              NOT NULL,
   invlaid_from   DATETIME              NOT NULL
)
```

The constraint I want to apply is that there should never be any entries for the same "fk_item_id" with overlapping dates.

Note:

invalid_from is the instant immediately after the valid period.
This means that the following two periods are fine...

- '2008 Jan 01 00:00' -> '2008 Feb 01 00:00'  (All of Jan)
- '2008 Feb 01 00:00' -> '2008 Mar 01 00:00'  (All of Feb)

I can check that rule in a trigger.  When the trigger does find an illegal insert/update, however, what is the best way to prevent the "illegal" inserts/updates from happening?

(If *inserted* includes two valid records and two invalid records, can I stop just the two invalid records?)

Cheers,
Dems.

**EDIT:**

In the case I had above, a constraint using a function worked well. But I never worked out why the RAISERROR didn't work in the trigger version.

I thought it was because the trigger is an AFTER trigger, and that I'd need a BEFORE trigger, but that doesn't appear to be an option...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't delete directly from inserted (updates to the logical tables raise an error) but you can join back to the source table as seen below

```
create table triggertest (id int null, val varchar(20))
Go
create trigger after  on [dbo].triggertest
for Update  
as
Begin

    delete tt from triggertest tt inner join 
    inserted i on tt.id = i.id 
    where i.id = 9

End
GO
insert into triggertest values (1,'x')
insert into triggertest values (2,'y')
Update triggertest set id = 9 where id = 2
select * from triggertest
1, x
```

Also, you don't have to go the trigger route, you can also bind a check constraint to the return value of a function

```
Alter table myData WITH NOCHECK add 
Constraint  CHK_VALID CHECK (dbo.fx_CheckValid(id, valid_from , invalid_from) = 1 );
```

Comment: +1 for the Constraint -> UDF, I've done this and like how it works.

Answer (score 3):

Don't delete the records from the inserted table... that's silent failure.  The road to hell is paved in Partial Commits.

You need to [RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx), which is essentially what a [constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188066.aspx) would do.

Answer (score 0):

Raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger could modify the `valid_from` and/or `invlaid_from` `DATETIME`s of the "illegal" records to special values. A subsequent cleanup step could identify the "illegal" records.